# Should I run makemigrations and migrate when using mongodb in django?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

If I use mongodb in django project with the help of djongo third-party api should I have to use commands migrate and makemigrations again n again when ever I make changes in my models??

Comment: Have you tried reading documentation? https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#migration-free-model-changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does django with mongodb make migrations a thing of the past?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604565/does-django-with-mongodb-make-migrations-a-thing-of-the-past)